# Something twitches in someone

Tags: meaning, usage

What does "something twitch in someone" means? How else would you use it in sentence?

> He said: "As soon as I saw them start CPR, ***something twitched in*** me. You always hope that, if you have a defibrillator and get there quickly, they will respond to at least two or three shocks. The longer the resuscitation, the less the chances of survival. But this is a very fit 23-year-old and those attending him are trained in CPR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idiomatic in a physical context with "me" would be **inside**.

> Something twitched **inside me**.
>
> Something twitched **in|inside my chest**.

**in me** is normally used to refer to a mental or emotional feeling.

> Something in me snapped and I went berserk.

So in your sentence "twitched in me" is probably referring to an emotional feeling, not a physical sensation, but speaking of the emotion figuratively as though it were a physical sensation.